# Генерация XML в процедуре

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть процедура которая возвращает набор данных и XML.

```
SELECT  'XMLRES' as OBJECT_NAME,                
               0 as SCORE,
               0 as MASK,
               0 as ROWSCOUNT,
               (XMLElement("XMLRES",
                    (SELECT (XMLElement("Elements",
                        XMLAgg(XMLElement("Element",
                        XMLElement("Name", e.SCOPENAME),
                        XMLElement("Count", e.SCOPECOUNT),
                            (SELECT(XMLElement("SubElements",
                                XMLAgg(XMLElement("SubElement",
                                    XMLElement("SubName", sub.SUBSCOPE_NAME),
                                    XMLElement("SubCount", sub.SUBSCOPE_COUNT)))))
                             FROM subscopes sub WHERE sub.SCOPE_NAME = e.SCOPENAME)))))
                     FROM all_elements e ) ,
                    (SELECT(XMLElement("Tags",
                        XMLAgg(XMLElement("Tag",
                            XMLElement("TagID", t.TAG_ID),
                            XMLElement("TagCount", t.TAGCOUNT)))))
                     FROM  all_tags t))
                ).GetStringVal() as XMLRES
FROM DUAL;
```

При вызове данного запроса, при генерации XML падает ошибка:

`ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`

Если заменить `.GetStringVal()` на `.getClobVal()` и приоброзовать значение колонки в CLOB, то все равно падает эта ошибка.

Какие еще есть варианты получения XML в ORACLE в моем случае?

Answer (score 1):

Очень сложно дать ответ на не полный запрос, но все же попробую.

Если я правильно вас понял, то второй запрос не выполняется у вас в принципе, пока вы не поставите getClobVal(), но это ломает запрос с юнионом. По правилам оракла каждая колонка при юнионе должна иметь тот же тип данных, что и соответствующая ей во всех последующих запросах. Т.е. если первая колонка в первом запросе NUMBER, то и во всех последующих запросах она должна быть NUMBER.

Поэтому для решения вашей проблемы необходимо преобразовать соответствующую XMLRES колонку из первого запроса к CLOB. Используйте для этого функию TO_CLOB.

Comment: эта же колонка в другом юнионе передается как NULL. Оба запроса выполняются вместе, но переполнение буфера происходит во втором, который я скинул. Даже, если этот запрос выполнить без юниона - все равно происходить ошибка "character string buffer too small".

Comment: Я немного изминил формулировку вопроса, чтобы убрать путаницу.

Comment: преобразование к клобу нужно в любом случае, т.к. VARCHAR2 поддерживает только 4 тысячи символов. разбираться нужно со второй ошибкой.

Comment: второй вопрос работает, если не использовать юнион, но использовать getClobVal?

Comment: нет, второй запрос при вызывает ошибку "character string buffer too small" даже после приоброзования

Comment: Вроде удалось воспроизвести ошибку. Попробуй выполнить

    SELECT  'XMLRES' as OBJECT_NAME,                
                   0 as SCORE,
                   0 as MASK,
                   0 as ROWSCOUNT,
                   (XMLElement("XMLRES",
                        (SELECT(XMLElement("Tags",
                            XMLAgg(XMLElement("Tag",
                                XMLElement("TagID", t.TAG_ID),
                                XMLElement("TagCount", t.TAGCOUNT)))))
                         FROM  all_tags t))
                    ).GetClobVal() as XMLRES
    FROM DUAL

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46287/discussion-between-okdel-and-localuser).